# Passing next character to command

Tags: macros

I have a command defined as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\@withstar}[3]{We have star #1, #2, #3}
\newcommand{\@withoutstar}[3]{We have #1, #2, #3}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mycmd{%
  \@ifnextchar *%
  {\@firstoftwo{\@withstar}} %
  {\@withoutstar}
}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\mycmd{first}{second}{and third}
\mycmd*{first}{second}{and third}
\end{document}
```

I want to define another command that just passes the next character to `\mycmd` and sets specific arguments. Something along the lines of

```
\newcommand\newcmd[1]{\mycmd\nextchar{first}{,second}}
```

Then I can call it like

```
 \newcmd{and third}
```

or

```
 \newcmd*{and third}
```

I understand that I can repeat the test for next char (using `@ifnextchar`) inside the definition of `\newcmd`, but I would like to avoid that if possible because in my real situation `\mycmd` tests for many characters, not just *.

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments, but your request might be easier to achieve with `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentCommand` and argument specifier features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
\def\newcmd#1#{\mycmd#1{first}{,second}}
```

`#1` will be all tokens between `\newcmd` and `{` which will be empty or `*` in your examples.

Comment: This works! However, is there a way to manipulate the remaining arguments? For example, something like this `\def\newcmd#1#{\mycmd#1{first}{,second}{#2 and #3}}`

Comment: @Tohiko `\def\newcmd#1#{\zzz{#1}}`  then `\def\zzz#1#2#3{\mycmd#1{first}{,second}{#2 and #3}}`

Comment: Can you please explain how introducing `\zzz` helps? In the beginning I tried `\def\newcmd#1#2#3{\mycmd#1{first}{,second}{#2 and #3}}` but the mode `\newcmd{third}{fourth}` did not work. I am not 100% sure why introducing `\zzz` seems to fix everything.

Comment: the special form `#1#` (which was why I used def not newcommand) is only available for the _last_ argument (it grabs up the the first `{` so you need a one-argument command to grab the * or nothing before the first `{` and after that can just use standard \def or \newcommand @Tohiko

Answer (score 2):

No code duplication with `xparse` and no auxiliary macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{smmm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {We have star #2, #3, #4}
    {We have #2, #3, #4}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newcmd}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\mycmd*}{\mycmd}{first}{second}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{first}{second}{and third}

\mycmd*{first}{second}{and third}

\newcmd{and third}

\newcmd*{and third}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution duplicate the character check using `\IfBooleanTF`? In my real application I have many checks that I need to do on the first character not just `*`.

Comment: @Tohiko I can't guess code you don't tell about, sorry

Comment: I do explain this particular point at the end of my original post. But no worries, thanks for directing me to `xparse`.